# x710 VF use dpdk rte_flow_valida() return Function not implemented

Tags: virtualization, dpdk

OS:CentOS 7.3

DPDK:19.08

I use one `X710` NIC, create 2 VFs in kernel driver `i40e`, and bind `vfio-pci` driver on VF 0 and Start a DPDK PMD application.

Then I try to create a Flow Rule use `rte_flow`, but it returns -38, **Function not implemented** when I called `rte_flow_validate()`.

Does it means this VF doesn't support `rte_flow API`? or there are some configure or flags need to be set on VF?

Comment: Please share the code snippet to understand which functionality are you trying to offload from VF NIC?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

DPDK RTE_FLOW are supported on both PF and VF for X710 (Fortville) NIC, with actions like

1. RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_QUEUE
2. RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_DROP
3. RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_PASSTHRU
4. RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_MARK
5. RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_RSS

The return value `-38` for DPDK API is not `Function not implemented`, but actually `I40E_ERR_OPCODE_MISMATCH`. This means either Lookup parameters or match cases are improperly configured. Code Snippet that works on X710 VF, shared below

```
/* configure for 2 RX queues */

struct rte_flow_attr attr = { .ingress = 1 };
struct rte_flow_item pattern[10];
struct rte_flow_action actions[10];
struct rte_flow_item_eth eth;
struct rte_flow_item_eth eth_mask;
struct rte_flow_item_vlan vlan;
struct rte_flow_item_vlan vlan_mask;
struct rte_flow_item_ipv4 ipv4;
struct rte_flow_item_ipv4 ipv4_mask;
struct rte_flow *flow;
struct rte_flow_action_mark mark = { .id = 0xdeadbeef };
struct rte_flow_action_queue queue = { .index = 0x3 };

memset(&pattern, 0, sizeof(pattern));
memset(&actions, 0, sizeof(actions));
memset(&attr, 0, sizeof(attr));
attr.group = 0;
attr.priority = 0;
attr.ingress = 1;
attr.egress = 0;

memset(&eth_mask, 0, sizeof(struct rte_flow_item_eth));
pattern[0].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_ETH;
pattern[0].spec = &eth;
pattern[0].last = NULL;
pattern[0].mask = NULL;

memset(&vlan_mask, 0, sizeof(struct rte_flow_item_vlan));
pattern[1].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_VLAN;
pattern[1].spec = &vlan;
pattern[1].last = NULL;
pattern[1].mask = NULL;


/* set the dst ipv4 packet to the required value */
pattern[1].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_IPV4;
pattern[1].spec = NULL;
pattern[1].last = NULL;
pattern[1].mask = NULL;

pattern[2].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_UDP;
pattern[2].spec = NULL;
pattern[2].last = NULL;
pattern[2].mask = NULL;

/* end the pattern array */
pattern[3].type = RTE_FLOW_ITEM_TYPE_END;

/* create the drop action */
actions[0].type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_MARK;
actions[0].conf = &mark;
actions[1].type = RTE_FLOW_ACTION_TYPE_END;
```

note: request @myzhu in comments to share the actual code snippet to root cause the issue too.

Comment: Thank you , varghese. I just use the dpdk example

Comment: Example :Flow_filtering and change nothing. It works once today, but never works now

Comment: @myzhu are you saying the example code-shared by me works once and then it did not work? If yes, there is something wrong in VF usage. Can we do alive debug?

Comment: No, @ Vipin Varghese, I mean the RTE_FLOW example in DPDK source code----`flow_filtering`.
I create VF in kernel mode and use `dpdk-devbind.py` bind one VF in vfio-pci, and Run `flow_filtering` on it. I up the pf before i use the vf and set VF trust on.

Comment: ahh ok, @myzhu you are stating, with the example code given in the answer you are able to make flow filtering working. Is  that right? If not, I am happy to check (live debug) / The same code snippet works with VF on X710.

Comment: It works once ,and it failed till now. I tryed reboot the server,but doesn't work. It return `-38`  and output the log `Function not implemented` . I don't know if the NIC register or flags or something others not set correctly.

Comment: My company develop environment can't connect to Internet, Maybe we can't debug alive, But I will try your code right now.

Comment: hmm, this looks liek more of hardware or firmware or configuration issues. Can we live debug?

Comment: can you find the NIC firmware  version?

Comment: Firmware version : 6.01 0x800035cf 1.1747.0

Comment: recommended Firmware version: 7.00 0x80004cdb. Please update and retry

Comment: But it can run correctly on pf.

Comment: @myzhu with the right firmware version and dpdk version I am able to get RTE_FLOW working with X710 with VF and PF alike. Since there is no live debug shared and limited information about your setup, I can also suggest the issue could be firmware for VF.  the same code works on VF x710 without any issues.

Comment: I update the firmware to latest 8.40, it does not work.

Comment: @myzhu live debug? surprise why rte_flow_validate is failing on your system

Comment: @myzhu as shared multiple times I am open to help in live debug to understand why rte_flow_validate is failing on vf on your setup most times and passes a few times. Aer you able to come for live debug?

Comment: sorry，our environment is isolated from the Internet physically，so we cannot debug alive. Our PF uses driver i40e, not the igb_uio. Does affect the result?

Comment: @myzhu the question I am asking again and again is `you have mentioned rte_flow, but it returns -38, Function not implemented when I called rte_flow_validate()`. With the code snippet on my environment with PF (Linux driver i40e) and VF (igb_uio) returns without error. So the question is `are you still getting return as -38 for rte_flow_validate?`

Comment: Yes, the return value from rte_flow_validate is still -38.

Comment: Is there anything special in port init in your code?

Comment: @myzhu none there is no special port init. Same code works on VF X710. Hence please share 1) `your code snippet which fails`  2) `lshw -c net -businfo` 3) `ethtool -i [VF kernel interface]` 4) `sudo lspci -vnks [PCIe BDF of the VF]`

Comment: I add some logs in `rte_flow_validate()` and find it return in `return -rte_error;` which means ops is NULL and `rte_flow_ops *ops = rte_flow_ops_get(portid, error)` not success.